# Increment or decrement an input's ng-model using ng-keyup

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, dom-events

I'd like to use `ng-keyup` to watch for the up and down arrow keys and increment or decrement the value in an input. This seems like it should be straightforward, but this fiddle does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/a8tgW/3/

html

```
<div  ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="minPotatoes" ng-keyup="onKeyup($event, minPotatoes)" />
  <input type="text" ng-model="maxPotatoes" ng-keyup="onKeyup($event, maxPotatoes)" />
</div>
```

js

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.onKeyup = function (evt, val) {
    if(evt.keyCode === 40) {
      val -= 1
      console.log("decrementing val", val)
    } else if (evt.keyCode === 38) {
      val += 1
      console.log("incrementing val", val)
    }
  }
  $scope.minPotatoes = 2;
  $scope.maxPotatoes = 10;
}
```

I've tried using `$apply`, but a digest is already in progress. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22466842/why-wont-ng-keypress-change-ng-model-values?rq=1) question, but it uses an external listener which doesn't have access to the model reference.

I could reference the scope value directly, instead of the passed in value, but it would be less coupled if the key handler had no knowledge of the model it was impacting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you want to be changing the scope variable and not the local val variable.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="potatoCount" ng-keyup="onKeyup($event, 'potatoCount')" />

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.onKeyup = function (evt, val) {
        if(evt.keyCode === 40) {
            --$scope[val];
            console.log("decrementing val");
        } else if (evt.keyCode === 38) {
            ++$scope[val];
            console.log("incrementing val");
        }
    };
    $scope.potatoCount = 42;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ALjR5/2

Comment: I thought it passed a reference. I need it to, in fact, because the actual use case is a slider with two handles. The keyup handler has no knowledge of which model to increment/decrement.

Comment: Ok check out v2 of the fiddle. You can pass the scope variable name as a string instead of the current value, then increment `$scope[val]`.

Comment: Clever! I wrote custom directives, one for `keypress-uparrow` and one for `keypress-downarrow`. This works, but I like yours better!

Comment: I found this works better if you bind it to `ng-keydown` http://jsfiddle.net/ALjR5/12/ because you can then hold down your `up` or `down` arrow keys